# Android - get next navigation step in my app

Tags: android, navigation, maps

Hypothetical question, I don't have any code yet or a plan.

Is it possible to get Google maps (or ideally any other nav app) next navigation step e.g. In 100m Left turn, in my app I will be developing?

What I want to achieve, I want to send those to other external device from my android device.

Before I even start, is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsResponses)

If you scroll a little bit down [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Legs) you can see a section named steps.
These are informations including directions and distances to the next step
They have also geolocations included in those step, so you could check whether you are in the near of a waypoint

I hope that's helpful

Comment: Thank you for reply, but that's not quiet what I meant. Your solution require me to implement whole Google maps navigation in my app if I am not mistaken. I wanted soemthing to try to catch what genuine Google maps app is doing currently or other navigation napo like waze. For Google maps I had idea to maybe try to read navigation notification which contains some of navigation steps, but that's not very elegant